# Open twitter account from android app

Tags: android, twitter

I am trying to open twitter account from my android application by using the following code. But it fails and getting this message.

> cannot get users at this time please try again later

Code

```
public static void openTwitterHandle(String mTwitterHandle, FragmentActivity activity) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {


        activity.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.twitter.android", 0);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://user?user_id=" + mTwitterHandle));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/" + mTwitterHandle));
    }
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this (change `user_id` to `screen_name`):

```
"twitter://user?screen_name=" + mTwitterHandle
```